# How to embed VTT captions (custom subtitles) on YouTube Player videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, plyr.js

I checked the documentation of [YouTube Player API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), but it does not specify any [parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) to add a path to our own VTT file for captions.

I also came across [Plyr.JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/plyr), but I am not sure if it can be used to achieve the same.

So, is there any way to play our own subtitle on YouTube videos?

Answer (score 1):

I found an indirect temporary way to do it.

1. Call this endpoint to get the direct link for the YouTube video:
   https://maadhav-ytdl.herokuapp.com/video_info.php?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc

(Source code for this server: https://github.com/Maadhav/youtube-downloader-API )

2. `decodeURIComponent()` the link that you get.
3. Then embed the video link and your captions track in  tag [as described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track).

---

Works as on December 2020.

Comment: Another endpoint if above does not work: https://www.yt2mp3.ws/developers ([Source code](https://github.com/matthew-asuncion/Fast-YouTube-to-MP3-Converter-API))